# Powershell in C# Return Command Output

Tags: c#, iis, powershell

I'm new to bringing C# and Powershell together, but am hoping to create a web page that leverages Powershell in the back end.  I realize that what I am doing can be done solely with C#, but would like to figure this out for other applications.

Essentially, I am taking the name of a new web application from a web form and getting the authenticated user's username for physical path mapping.

My Powershell code works correctly (even when copying it from Pipeline.Commands[0] directly), but it does not appear to do anything when I run it.  I get parameter errors in the result variable if I force one (ex: make -physicalpath a non-existent path), but with all parameters correct, the variable result only contains one blank item.

I see many similar questions to this one, but do not see s definitive answer.

Does this sound like a C# or IIS Powershell module issue?  Any ideas how I get more information returned from my command?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  String username = getUser();
  String physicalPath = "S:\\WebSites\\" + username + "\\public_html\\" + TextBox1.Text; 

  // Create Powershell Runspace
  Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

  runspace.Open();

  // Create pipeline and add commands
  Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
  pipeline.Commands.AddScript(
    "Import-Module WebAdministration; set-psdebug -trace 1; " +

    "New-WebApplication -Site MySite" +
    " -Name " + TextBox1.Text +
    " -PhysicalPath " + physicalPath +
    " -ApplicationPool WebSites -Verbose -force");

  pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

  // Execute Script
  Collection<PSObject> results = new Collection<PSObject>();
  try
  {
    results = pipeline.Invoke();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    results.Add(new PSObject((object)ex.Message));
  }

  // Close runspace
  runspace.Close();

  //Script results to string
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (PSObject obj in results)
  {
    stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
  }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it should work. You should check the error stream and see if there are messages there (ie: "Destination element already exists").

I'd also suggest you consider using the PowerShell 2 APIs as in this blog post:

http://huddledmasses.org/how-to-invoke-powershell-and-use-the-results-from-csharp/

If you're using that, you can check the ps.Streams.Error to make sure it's empty...

Comment: Thanks Jaykul--I'll give that a try when I get a chance and post back.

Comment: @Jykul, link does not work. I don't need it now, but other users may benefit from info within the answer or updated link.

Comment: Ugh. You'd think linking to my own blog would be safe, because why would I take that down!? (long story) ... for now the first paragraph is the answer. The link was just extra advice (and slightly out of date anyway, because PowerShell 4 and 5 have improved the APIs further).